# Queue not continuing?

Tags: python, multithreading

I know there's something stupid I'm doing, but I can't figure this out! I'm testing by doing 1 thread. It's supposed to add up to ten items in the queue, wait for it to finish, and then say "Finished". The thread function has q.task_done() at the end of it. But it'll say "Task Done" but then it just pauses and doesn't ever say "Finished".

```
def helper(q):
     print("Started")
     ....
     q.task_done()
     print("Task done")

def main():
    q = Queue(maxsize=0)
    recid = 9000000
    num_threads = 1

    for i in range(num_threads):
        worker = Thread(target=helper, args=(q))
        worker.setDaemon(True)
        worker.start()

    while recid > 0:
        batch.clear()
        for x in range(10):
            q.put(recid)
            print("Added request.")
            recid -= 1

        print("Waiting for threads to finish.")
        q.join()
        print("Finished")
```

Comment: You have to call `q.task_done()` *for every time put was called*. If you're only calling it once, then `.join()` will just sit there, waiting on the rest of them.

Comment: Hmmm but I was trying to make it so one thread was active, but it would load up 10 items in the queue, and that one thread would process through all 10 items before finishing. Am I just thinking of it wrong?

Comment: No, you can still do it that way.. but you've called `q.put(recid)` 10 times. The queue won't be "done" until `q.task_done()` has been called 10 times on the other end. It's not a way to signal that "all of the work in the queue is done", it's a way to signal "I've completed *one task*."

Comment: How do I signal all work in the queue is done? Check if queue is empty?

Comment: Basically, just put `q.task_done()` in whatever loop is handling your queued objects in `helper`.

Comment: `q.join()` will return when, *at any point*, `q.task_done()` has been called the same number of times as `q.put()`. It's entirely up to your code to decide when to call `q.join()`.

Comment: Sorry I just realized the indentation got messed up when I pasted it in!! Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

worker was dead before you called q.join(). maybe try to add some delays in helper() waiting for q.put()

```
def helper(q):
    print("Started")
    time.sleep(1)                 # wait for main() q.put()
    while not q.empty():          # until queue is empty
        print("request", q.get())
        q.task_done()             # trigger q.join in main()
        print("Task done")
        time.sleep(1)             # wait for next q.put() if exists
```

Updated:

Basically, q.task_done() in helper() triggers q.join() in main() and worker.join() will be triggered once helper() is exited. An example code is as followed:

```
def main():
    q = Queue(maxsize=0)
    recid = 100
    num_threads = 4

    while recid > 0:
        for i in range(num_threads):
            print('''******** Hired Worker %d ********'''%(i),)
            worker = Thread(target=helper, args=(q,))
            worker.setDaemon(True)
            worker.start()

            # batch.clear()
            for x in range(3):
                q.put(recid)
                print("Request Worker %d to do %d."%(i, recid))
                recid -= 1

            ##############################################################
            # Comment these lines when you are ready to test multiThread 
            ##############################################################
                print("Waiting Worker %d to finish %d."%(i, recid))
                q.join()    # triggered by q.task_done in helper()
                print("Worker %d Finished %d"%(i, recid))

            print("Waiting for Worker %d to leave."%i)
            worker.join()   # triggered once helper() is exited
            print("!!!!!!!! Worker %d left !!!!!!!!"%i)
            ##############################################################    

    time.sleep(5)      # wait until all requests are finished.
    print("Finished")
```

Once you are happy with join() of Thread and Queue. You may try multithreading by commenting that block of code.

Comment: `q.join()` is a function called on the Queue object, not a Thread object.

Comment: You did, however, provide code that would resolve the issue -- `q.task_done()` is called inside a loop instead of once (and only once) at the end of processing.